# cflock on application variables that rarely change

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

We currently have a series of variables that are loaded into the application scope that rarely change.

By rarely change, I mean that they are strings like phone numbers, or simple text values that appear on a website and may change once a week or once a month.

Since we are reading these variables and because they rarely change, is there any requirement to encapsulate these inside a cflock ?

I think it would be alot of coding overhead to wrap these variables inside a cflock as the template may contain upwards of 20 instances of these static variables.

Any advice on this greatly appreciated

Comment: How exactly do you change them?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would say you do not need to. These variables are essentially constants.

However, you need to assess this yourself. You need to answer the question, 'what would be the ramifications of these variables being read with stale data?'

This means, if as in your example the wrong phone number is used on a request is this a disaster? If that is a problem that you can live with then you can make no changes. If however there are variables that are used in calculations or ones that will cause unacceptable problems if they are stale, then you will need to lock access to these. In this way you can focus your efforts on where you need to and minimise the additional work.

As an aside if you do need to lock any variables then a good pattern to use is to store them inside a CFC instance that is stored in application scope. This way you can handle all the locking in the CFC and your calling code remains simple.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of ACF, Railo, etc... you are using I would suggest that data like this might be better stored in the cache and not in the application scope. The cache can have more persistences through restarts, etc... as well and could be a more efficient way to go.

Take a look at the cacheput, cacheget, cachedelete, etc... functions in the documentation. I believe this was functionality was added in CF9 and Railo 3.2.

Taking it one step further you could simply cache the entire output that uses them for X time as well, so that each time that part is loaded it only has to load one thing from the cache instead of the twenty or so times you mention.

If you are going to store them in the application scope then you only really need to have the cflock around the part of the code that updates them and lock it at the application level. That way anything wanting to read them will have to wait for it to finish updating them before it can read them anyway as the update thread will have a lock on the application scope.